# R JIT compiler - is there a way to automatically pre-compile all functions in a script? (for use with shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, jit, shiny-server

Is there a way to get R to precompile all functions in a script?

The reason it matters is because the script is code for rshiny. I'd like to push forward the byte compiling to occur when the server starts up rather when the user is requesting a page.

I know cmpfun() could be used to compile one function at a time and modify function calls accordingly, but I'd like to do this without maintaining the extra boilerplate code if it's possible.

Comment: I haven't tried it before, but it looks like you can call `cmpfile` on an R script containing function definitions, and then use `loadcmp` to get the compiled expressions back into the `.GlobalEnv`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the JIT from `compiler` with:

```
library(compiler)
enableJIT(3)
```

or set the environment variable `R_ENABLE_JIT` to non-negative (3 is the highest amount of compilation). I did a quick experiment with my Shiny app and this seemed to produce no benefit at all, so maybe something is not working correctly. [This page](http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/04/speed-up-your-r-code-using-a-just-in-time-jit-compiler/) provides a few more details on R compilation options.